# Angular not loading on Hapi/Inert

Tags: angularjs, hapi.js

I'm trying to build a very simple Hapi / Angualr page using Hapi 17.

I have a simple Angular based index.html that populates two tags from data set in the controller

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <label>
        {{ hello }} {{ world }}
    </label>
</div>
```

When I bootstrap the index page from Webstorm the bindings work as expected.

I have set up a very simple Hapi / Inert server do server the index.html. The page loads the raw HTML as expected so that side of things is working.

**However** 
when I load the page the Angular bindings display only raw text ie. `{{ hello }} {{ world }}`

There's a plunker [here](https://embed.plnkr.co/4LnDGNsBnXEdvuwIUwpt/)

Comment: Your plunker seems to work

Comment: I couldn't find a way of getting the plunker to run the server.js and hook up to hapi/inert - the angular side runs ok on its own as mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I was using the wrong server.route definition from the Inert docs.

The single file route (below) cannot see the javascript files which contain the definition of the angular application

```
server.route({
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/{path*}',
    handler: {
        file: 'page.html'
    }
});
```

Moving to the following example, along with moving the front-end files to a "public" folder, makes it work

```
server.route({
        method: 'GET',
        path: '/{param*}',
        handler: {
            directory: {
                path: '.',
                redirectToSlash: true,
                index: true,
            }
        }
    });
```